# Raspbian GUI keeps asking for password

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, password

As indicated in the title, I'm having some issues when booting my RPi (3b).
More specificly, when loading the GUI desktop, it keeps asking me for my password. I give the correct one, it shows a black screen then asks for it again.

I made the "investigations steps" I found here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57366/101006 and here is what I found in the *lightdm log file*:
[image: lightdm log]

[image: lightdm log end]

**Note:** The second picture serves only to show the end of the highlighted line

I also tried to change the rights of the .Xauthority file with the *chown* command but it doesn't help.  Idem when I try with "pi":

`sudo chown -R pi /home/pi`

```
sudo chown pi:pi .Xauthority
```

None of these command help.

For the next of the answer I don't know which package to remove with `dpkg purge` and I don't want to remove some files that I won't be able to re-install after that.

I don't know what to do now to avoid being asked for my password, any idea ?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: I didn't know how to copy and send it somewhere I could get it since none of the default interface network works ...

Comment: Ah.. ok. You took photos from the RasPi monitor, isn't it?

Comment: When it asked me for the password, I made Ctrl+Alt+F1 and I went into the terminal. Then I opened the lightdm log file and I took the picture with my phone

Answer (score 0):

Installing desktop envirnonment will solve the problem

To install XFCE, enter the following command:

**sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-terminal**